# Should we remove the "nuance" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

[nuance](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuance) seems to be used to indicate that a question is subtle or difficult. I'm not sure if it's a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) or not. On the other hand, it's used like [hard](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard), and the other connotations that it brings are well-covered by [differences](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differences) and [pronunciation](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciation).

> **If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.** Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like [beginner], [subjective], and [best-practices], are useless by themselves — they tell you nothing at all about the content of the question.
>
> **If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag.** In a cruel, ironic twist, the meaning of the tag [subjective] itself … is actually subjective. Ditto for [best-practices] and [beginner]. Best practices to whom? Beginner by what criteria? These tags are impossible to define by anything remotely resembling an objective metric. In comparison, the the meaning of tags like [java], [c#], and [javascript] are crystal clear to all but the nuttiest of nutbags.

Comment: Not sure if it's a meta-tag or not, but it does not seem to be used consistently, which is a bad sign.

Comment: I vote for it being removed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it should be removed. Nuance is clearly a meta tag:

> they tell you nothing at all about the content of the question